# How to research what resources are leaked by which application (not a full ATOM table issue)

Tags: .net, delphi, windows-7, resources, plsqldeveloper

Some application on my system is leaking resources. But I don't know what it is leaking and which application.

The leak causes other applications to fail with error messages like this:

> System Error. Code: 8. Not enough storage is available to process this command.

What tools and/or steps can I use to find out which application is leaking and what it is leaking?

note: I have

- 40% of memory free (of a total of 8 gigabytes)
- 15 gigabytes space free on the boot/system SSD drive
- all the rights I need (can be Admin when needed)
- a Windows 7 development workstation (with things like Visual Studio 2013, Delphi 2007, PL/SQL Developer 9, Office 2013, McAfee 8, IE 11, Chrome 44, Cisco Jabber)
- some developed applications and services running (but not many)
- Our Delphi services and applications run with FastMM in full debug mode and don't show memory leaks.
- <strike>about 200 string ATOMS in use (see dump at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a4954baa256ddacbe1a8) so it's not a full ATOM table issue.</strike> It *was* ATOMS, but while refactoring the code by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108091/jordi-corbilla and https://stackoverflow.com/users/112670/christian-b-almeida I accidentally killed very odd atoms in https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1deb17123d57f160c4b2 which I will answer below.
- standard Windows 7 heaps with a large Desktop heap: `SharedSection=1024,20480,768`
- it is not the RegisterWindowsMessages either: about 1000 of them in total: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/027b26809d66970b25b8
- it isn't a window handle count either, as `Testlimit -u` can happily allocate 10k USER handles: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7296453116c5826d632d

Since it could just as well be one of our own developed applications, I ask it here instead of superuser/serverfault. We don't get this on our servers though.

---

Since I can't answer, here is the elaboration:

The tooling in the "non-duplicate" answer can't pinpoint the source for various reasons:

- they call Windows API functions with wrong data
- they presume Thread IDs are the same as Process IDs
- they contain very limited source code (the most interesting UI application is lacking)
- the binaries of the incomplete source code don't function well using truckloads of CPU and not responding to the UI after initial clicks
- the source does not explain what they do and why they do it

I'm in the midst of combining those pieces of code and refactoring it to a useful console application that:

- shows Atoms and Registered Windows messages
- indicates by which Application
- shows percentage used
- can better estimate what ATOMS to free

That way, dumping the output over time and correlating the diffs it might be possible to zoom in to the offending problem.

The offending ATOM leaks look like this:

`````````
Atom 0xD8F8 with name "-%D4#!`````(W!```````@W#````````"
Atom 0xD8F9 with name "-%D4#!`````HT!```````@W#````````"
Atom 0xD8FA with name "-%D4#!`````+R!```````@W#````````"
Atom 0xD8FB with name "-%D4#!`````3P!```````@W#````````"
Atom 0xD8FC with name "-%D4#!`````*S!```````@W#````````"
Atom 0xD8FD with name "-%D4#!`````KO!```````@W#````````"
Atom 0xD8FE with name "-%D4#!`````,T!```````@W#````````"
`````````

Statistics look like this:

```
Total Global Atoms: 6405
Total is 39 percent of maximum 16384 Global Atoms.
Total Registered WindowsMessages: 1940
Total is 11 percent of maximum 16384 Registered WindowsMessages.
```

Comment: have a look at [FastMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) and at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075554/how-do-i-turn-on-off-fastmm-memory-leak-reporting-under-delphi-xe)

Comment: @fantaghirocco i don't think it's not a memory issue: I've plenty of memory free. Our Delphi services and applications run with FastMM and don't show memory leaks (I will add that to the question).

Comment: See [System Error. Code: 8. Not enough storage is available to process this command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/507853/576719). Resource Heap storage shortage.

Comment: Jeroen, don't you think it is hard for us to tell where your system is leaking resources, remotely? "Not enough storage" means what kind of storage exactly? FWIW I did not downvote, but I can understand if someone did.

Comment: Fwiw, what the linked "Not enough storage" q which this one is said to duplicate, it doesn't seem to mention that this error can arise in the course of a Delphi app invoking an external COM object (the one for the Lotus Notes client, iirc).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis that's what I want to find out: which resource is leaking. I'll try the ATOM table thing (first need to get that working in Delphi 2007) and report back next week.

Comment: @MartynA I'll try to figure that out as well. Thanks.

Comment: @LURD it is not the resource heap, not the ATOM table and not the RegisterWindows Messages table. Any more ideas?

Comment: @LURD it was atoms, but not the Delphi based atoms mentioned in the other answer. I'd like to elaborate here in an answer on how and why the tools in the other answer were only partially of help especially as they can't point the offending program.

Comment: Ok, question is opened.

Comment: @LURD thanks a lot. Will update the answer over time.

Answer (score 1):

It took a long time figuring out, and I will edit both the question over time.

The culprit are two kinds of Global ATOMs that are sometimes related. There are a few Delphi related Global ATOMs, but that is like 5% of the [total](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7f7e0c4e168c8ea62355).

First a lot of Global ATOMs are sporadically created with this pattern:

`````````
Global Atom 0xDE4E with name "-%D4#!`````Y0````````03(````````"
Global Atom 0xDE4F with name "-%D4#!`````Y$````````P[!````````"
...
Global Atom 0xDE66 with name "-%D4#!`````MG````````P[!````````"
Global Atom 0xDE67 with name "-%D4#!`````!'````````0)1````````"
...
Global Atom 0xEE0F with name "-%D4#!`````AJ!```````0('````````"
Global Atom 0xEE10 with name "-%D4#!`````BJ!```````0('````````"
`````````

Even less Global ATOMs are created with this pattern:

```
Global Atom 0xEE11 with name "MSAA:000034C0:00001950:00000701:000034C0:"
Global Atom 0xEE12 with name "MSAA:000034C0:000018C8:00000702:000034C0:"
...
Global Atom 0xEE25 with name "MSAA:000034C0:00001758:000006EC:000034C0:"
Global Atom 0xEE26 with name "MSAA:000034C0:0000197C:000006ED:000034C0:"
```

The combination of many "random" and a few "MSAA" seems to happen when I've been running "Microsoft Test Manager 2013" which seems to use [MSAA technology](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22MSAA%22%20%22Microsoft%20Test%20Manager%22&oq=%22MSAA%22). A log is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44080c2a20b98a5e8607

I'm in the midst to

1. refine and refactor the tool dumping this information
2. find more correlation on the "random" ATOMs (I've seen them occur when not running "Microsoft Test Manager 2013" yet.

I will update this answer when I zoom in on the cause, and have updates on the tool.

Comment: How did you find the source of the Global ATOMs?  How did you determine which application was causing the issue?